# Download arquivos zip de um link para uma pasta do PC através do R

Tags: r

Boa tarde

Preciso baixar os arquivos zip do seguinte site

```
ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/MarketData/
```

Gostaria de fazer o download via R, e que os arquivos fossem salvos no meu computador, porém não conheço comando para tal.

Como são muitos arquivos, baixá-los manualmente seria muito demorado.

Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim, usando o pacote `curl`:

```
library(curl)
library(readr)

url_opcoes <- "ftp://ftp.bmf.com.br/MarketData/Bovespa-Opcoes/"
con <- curl(url_opcoes)
arquivos <- read_delim(con, delim = " ", col_names = FALSE)$X4

for (x in arquivos) 
  curl_download(url = paste0(url_opcoes, x), destfile = paste0("data/", x))
```

Esse código baixaria todos os arquivos que estão no diretório Bovespa-Opcoes desse FTP.

Comment: Muito obrigado , resolveu o problema 

Saberia com implantar um código que impedisse de baixar arquivos já baixados anteriormente quando eu fosse atualizar a pasta com os dados rodando novamente o código

Comment: Existe uma função `list.files` que lista todos os arquivos dentro de uma pasta. Você pode usá-la e depois filtrar do vetor de arquivos só aqueles que não estão na pasta.

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda